# Javascript function definition error

Tags: javascript

```
var add = function addnums(a,b)
{
    return a+b;
}
alert("sum is " + addnums(10,20));
```

why can't i use `addnums` directly in the above Javascript ?

PS : I know other alternatives, the question is why the above specified method doesn't work.

Comment: Can you have two names....??

Comment: Good question :) I expected that it would just work the way you did it. So that you can either call the function via `addnums(1,2)` and via `add(1,2)`.

Comment: addnums() wont be visible in outer scope, its a Named Function Expression

Answer (score 0):

You can.

```
var add = function addnums(a,b)
{
    return a+b;
}
alert("sum is " + (function(a,b) { return a+b; })(10,20) );
```

Plus you may shorten the syntax:

```
var addnums = function(a,b) { ... }
```

or

```
function addnums(a,b) { ... }
```

Comment: Since all answers receive quick downvotes here, please explain why.

Comment: i am aware of other methods to make that work, just wanted to know why  the method in question doesn't work

Comment: You're not answering the question. The question is about why the function can't be referred to as `addnums` after it's been declared.

Comment: I see. Recently I've found some article about it, please wait for edit...

Answer (score -1):

You have an error writing the function write like the following:

```
var addnums = function(a,b)
{
    return a+b;
}
alert("sum is " + addnums(10,20));
```

:)

var add; is a declaration. Here add is declared and assigned a function you need not name the function after keyword function, variable name will take the function name when you define a function in this way. I think you understand now.

Comment: Besides the fact, that the syntax of the questioners code is correct, he wants to know why the named function isn't callable via its name.

Comment: function expression does not need a name, even if you name it it will not be called by that name. This is anonymous. You can say it is a drawback but there are more advantages than disadvantages. Check out this link   http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/07/06/function-declarations-vs-function-expressions/